# Python - nohup.out don't show print statement

Tags: python, nohup

Im new to python and web development, I have a basic issue I believe.
I'm running my server with pyramid, and I use nohup.out to write output to a file.

```
nohup ../bin/pserve development.ini
```

When I do `tail -f nohup.out`
I can see all the output coming from the `logging.info()` calls in my code.
but I don't see all the output from the `print()` calls.

what is the reason for that, and how can I set it that I will see the print() in the nohup file?

Answer (score 26):

You can use

```
nohup python -u python_script.py &
```

Comment: `-u: force the binary I/O layers of stdout and stderr to be unbuffered;
         stdin is always buffered; text I/O layer will be line-buffered;
         also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x`

Comment: `python -u` works for me while `stdbuf -oL -eL python` does not

Answer (score 11):

You can use stdbuf -oL to flush the print statements. Command will look like

```
nohup stdbuf -oL python python_script.py > nohup.out &
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, but I think your command needs to be ended with a `&` right?

Comment: This does not work. Tested on CentOS 7.4 with Python 3.7.6. The behavior is the same whether we use `stdbuf -oL` or not.

Answer (score 4):

Printed output is buffered when not to a terminal.  `nohup` replaces stdout with a non-terminal (a file, in fact).

In the absence of any code, all I can do is guess, but the most likely answer is that your output is buffered inside the python process, and when that buffer fills it will be flushed to `nohup.out`.  To see if this is the case, try adding a lot more prints to fill up the buffer faster.